# how to play video with the help of VideoView in android

Tags: android, video

I need to play a mp4 video in android which is not a streaming video. This is the URL of video.

```
http://swytchboard.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/102_1378616771.mp4
```

and this is the way what am using.

```
            MediaController media_Controller = new MediaController(context);
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            DetailedSwytchActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int height = dm.heightPixels;
            int width = dm.widthPixels;
            video_player_view.setMinimumWidth(width);
            video_player_view.setMinimumHeight(height);
            video_player_view.setMediaController(media_Controller);
            video_player_view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://swytchboard.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/102_1378616771.mp4"));
            video_player_view.start();
```

I tried so many ways but not getting success.

Thanks to in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
vv.setVideoPath(filename);
vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
vv.requestFocus();
vv.start();
```

to get file name use cursor

```
 Cursor videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);
 int video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow (MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
 String filename = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
```

Comment: am getting error as android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@42aa8f28 is not valid; is your activity running?